# How to solve "Secure Connection Failed" at Server Side Issue

Tags: php, ssl, server, web-hosting

I have just launched my website and installed SSL with it.

Site is working fine until visitor don't traveling at least for 3 or 4 page. and then the errors start coming like 'secure connection fail, connection restarted etc'

don't know why my user facing such issue, its not for just one just i have tried with multiple browsers as well but stuck at the same error.

Let me know if someone have solved or solution/idea of it.

Thanks!

Comment: sometime its shows
Chrome : "No data received"
Firefox: "The connection was reset"